# JS and Regex - Removing comma before a bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if sounds really trivial but:

I have the following line

```
var myString = 
    linear-gradient(to right, #f25f5c 0%,  #f25f5c 100%, #84dcc6 100%,  #84dcc6 100%, )
```

I want to remove the `,` at before that closing bracket if ever it exists.

I've used http://regexr.com/ to determine that my regex needs to be `,.\)` however how do i use this as JS?

Is this correct:

```
if (,.\.test(myString)) {
   //how do i remove that comma?
}
```

Alternatively if this is a really long winded way and someone know of something simplier in JS - would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: `/,\s*\)$/.test(str.trim())`

Comment: `myString = myString.replace(/,\s*\)$/, ")")`

Comment: Just to clarify, is the line exactly how it appears in your code or is it a quoted string `"linear-gradient(to right, #f25f5c 0%,  #f25f5c 100%, #84dcc6 100%,  #84dcc6 100%, )"`?

Comment: As appears (so without quotes). Also space after comma is supposed to be there.

Comment: `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters, so my suggestion should work.

Comment: Ok well that's a syntax error and won't run, so rather than trying to run the regex in js you'd need In IDE capable of regex searches or running macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
   var result= "linear-gradient(to right, #f25f5c 0%,  #f25f5c 100%, #84dcc6 100%,  #84dcc6 100%, )"
     .replace(/,\s*\)$/,')')
```

The regular expression is `/,\s*)\)$/` where:

- **`$`**  at the end of your string
- **`)`** you will look for the parenthesis
- **`\s*`** where the space is optional
- **`,`** between your comma and parenthesis